# Page submit on refresh when redirected from paytm payment response

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, payment-gateway

I am working on paytm payment gateway used it for customer payment on my site in codeigniter.
The issue is i have given a call back url to show success page.

```
$paytmparamList["CALLBACK_URL"]=base_url()."payment-succes";
```

But when i refresh this page it 
submits back and another transaction data is saved in my database. The paytm response is in post.

Code snippet is:

```
public function paymentConfirm(){

        header("Pragma: no-cache");
        header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
        header("Expires: 0");

        if(!empty($this->input->post())){
           ....
           ....
        }
}
```

Comment: keep your `$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;` in `config.php`

Comment: insert your data after payment successful response. if you send payment id to paytm then it gives you an error and it redirect to payment failed.